# Is `and` best practice

Tags: php, syntax

I came across this script at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php#78040

```
   /**
     Returns a formatted string based on camel case.
     e.g. "CamelCase" -> "Camel Case".
    */
    function FormatCamelCase( $string ) {
            $output = "";
            foreach( str_split( $string ) as $char ) {
                    strtoupper( $char ) == $char and $output and $output .= " ";
                    $output .= $char;
            }
            return $output;
    }
```

The curios Part Is  :

```
strtoupper( $char ) == $char and $output and $output .= " ";
```

My Question

- A detailed break down of `strtoupper( $char ) == $char and $output and $output .= " ";` and why its valid
- This would not work for `break` ,  `return` , `echo` but it works for any function including `print`
- Is this Best Practice
- Do such code have any advantages or disadvantages

Comment: I'd not use `and` in PHP, although it will work - use `&&` instead.

Comment: @halfer: it won't work with `&&`, because `and` has lower precedence than `.=` and `&&` - higher. So technically it will execute without errors, but won't behave as expected.

Comment: Thanks @zerkms. I wasn't aware that `&&` and `and` had different precedences - worth knowing!

Comment: What do you mean by valid? That it gives no syntax error?

Comment: @hakre it valid because `That it gives no syntax error` and the code runs fine ... just trying to understand the internal  workings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is same as

```
if (strtoupper( $char ) == $char) {
    if ($output) {
         $output .= " ";
    }  
}
```

For the code `A and B`, `B` will be executed if `A` is evaluated to true.

The difference between `&&` and `and` is `&&` has higher precedence than `and`, `.=` is between them.

Comment: "For the code A and B, B will be executed if A is evaluated to false." --- uhm, nope. It's the opposite actually. `and` behaves exactly the same as `&&` but with another precedence

Comment: But what really makes it valid ?? `and $output .= " "` when  did php support concatenation

Comment: @Baba: `and` has lower precedence, `.=` has higher; `and` has left associativity. This means that operands in `and` are executed from left to right and that right operand is executed only if left is true

Comment: @Baba PHP always support concatenation

Comment: @xdazz am sill lost .... see updated code for `is_bool($var) == true and $test .= "A" and is_bool($var) == true and $test .= "B"` it reruns `B1` instead of `AB`

Comment: @xdazz it was removed .. since it was just apache issue

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

As other answers have indicated, every subsequent statement is only executed if the preceding statement==true.

This is more relevant in code like: if(foo and bar) { //do something }

If foo==false then there is no need to waste time evaluating bar.

I can't say I use short-circuit evaluation to my advantage outside of boolean logic and for the sake of other coders looking at my code, I probably won't start now.

Comment: See updated code starting with `is_bool($var) == true` gives different result

Comment: I ran both of your examples and both times my output was:
string(2) "AB"

Comment: restarted Apache and everything is now AB

Comment: nice, I was going crazy trying to figure that one out ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
  strtoupper( $char ) == $char and $output and $output .= " ";
```

Is a sort of short hand if first it checks if it is a uppercase character if so he goes to the next and check if `$output` is not empty and then he add a space to $output

Its not the best practice but using one liners feels cool

And the advantage is that its cool
The disadvantage is that you need to read it over and over to understand it

Comment: @Baba: why should it be invalid?

Comment: @Baba because its calculating with booleans

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses have test it with boolean it arts funny .. see updated code

Answer (score 0):

strtoupper( $char ) == $char and $output and $output .= " ";

means

```
if(strtoupper( $char ) == $char && $output && $output.=" "){
// if string is equal than it checks for $output
//is that present?
// if  present than it checks for $output value
//and add a space to that if everything works fine than go to true part
}
```

Comment: `$output==""` is not the same as `$output .= " ";`

Comment: According to zerkms: _it won't work with `&&`, because `and` has lower precedence than `.=` and `&&` - higher._ http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

Answer (score 0):

you have got an expression here that consists of three sub-expressions concatenated with the logical `and` operator:

```
       strtoupper( $char ) == $char and $output and $output .= " ";
                             A      and    B    and       C
```

The order is this straight forward from left to right because of operator precedence.

Because that is, you can just go through. I think you understand what A and B and C does on it's own. However PHP will if any of those three will evaluate to `false` quit executing the whole expression. That expression runs until `false` are being executed (otherwise PHP couldn't say the outcome, see [Short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)).

It reads: Character is uppercase and output and add a space to output.

That sentence is wrong if character is not uppercase. So it would not be continued longer than:

It reads: Character is not uppercase.

Let's take the sentence and say that the character is uppercase. but no output:

It reads: Character is uppercase and no output.

And finally let's say there is output:

It reads: Character is uppercase and output and add a space to output.

Think of the programming language as a language to express something with.

It's just a common expression. Some programmers are not used to it to write expressions that expressive, in their mental model it's more that basic like if then else style of writing:

```
if (A) then if (b) then C.
```

It reads: If character is uppercase then if output then add a space to output.

Do what suits you best. And just read the code. It helps:

```
strtoupper( $char ) == $char and $output and $output .= " ";
```

Character is uppercase and output and add a space to output.